# Passing line from text file into script in a for loop

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu

Below I have a script that is working and is used to find file sizes in our Object Storage Architecture running on Ubuntu. The issue I am having is the script is written for checking one account at a time which works fine, but if I wanted to modify it to parse through multiple accounts one after another how would this be possible. Is there a way to pass a list of parameters from another text file to replace the variables at the top of the script?

For example if another text file, test.txt, had the following lines:

```
auto02 FfiBftkjgS8hnQn79Arj7PiHfvtsgn
qa04 s67aeYD6521pPgt7TknvGxKvF9WxNF
```

Is it possible to grab the user and key from the file above and replace it with the varibles at the top of this script in some kind of loop to go through all of the accounts?

```
#!/bin/bash

# Variables to be set
auth=http://sslabapi/auth/v1.0 # Auth URL
user=qa04 # Username
key=s67aeYD6521pPgt7TknvGxKvF9WxNF # Password
size=500000 # Minimum file size in bytes

# Env variables set
ST_AUTH="$auth"
ST_USER="$user"
ST_KEY="$key"

# Env variables exported
export ST_AUTH
export ST_KEY
export ST_USER

# Timestamp function
timestamp() {
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}

# Main Loop
containerList="$(swift list)"
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "$(timestamp): Account for $user" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "Starting check for files > $size bytes in the $user user account..."
for i in $containerList; do
    echo "*************************" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "Container $i" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "*************************" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "Container $i"
    IFS=$'\n'
    olist=($(swift list -l $i))
    for a in ${olist[@]}; do
        osize=`echo "$a" | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ $osize -gt "$size" ]; then
            echo "Found one: $a"
            echo "$a" >> bigFiles.txt
        fi
    done
done
```

Below is an edited version of my script to have the additions provided:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r user key
do
# Variables to be set
auth=http://sslabapi/auth/v1.0 # Auth URL
#user=$user # Username
#key=$key # Password
size=500000 # Minimum file size in bytes

# Env variables set
ST_AUTH="$auth"
ST_USER="$user"
ST_KEY="$key"

# Env variables exported
export ST_AUTH
export ST_KEY
export ST_USER

# Timestamp function
timestamp() {
    date +"%Y-%m-%d %T"
}

# Main Loop
containerList="$(swift list)"
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "$(timestamp): Account for $user" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++" >> bigFiles.txt
echo "Starting check for files > $size bytes in the $user user account..."
for i in $containerList; do
    echo "*************************" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "Container $i" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "*************************" >> bigFiles.txt
    echo "Container $i"
    IFS=$'\n'
    olist=($(swift list -l $i))
    for a in ${olist[@]}; do
        osize=`echo "$a" | awk '{print $1}'`
        if [ $osize -gt "$size" ]; then
            echo "Found one: $a"
            echo "$a" >> bigFiles.txt
        fi
    done
done
echo "...finished check!"
done < test.txt
```

Comment: Remove the lines `user=$user # Username` and 
`key=$key # Password`. The `read -r user key` already reads the variables `user` and `key`.

Comment: I edited the script above to remove the User and Key lines. The while read state works fine for the first line in Test.txt but it appears that it takes the entire second line of test.txt as the user variable which fails to authenticate because there is not a key.

Comment: To debug this you could add lines `echo "user=$user"` and `echo "key=$key"` in the loop or after setting the exported variables `echo "ST_USER=$ST_USER"` ... Which command actually uses the variables `ST_USER` etc.?

Comment: user=auto02
key=FfiBftkjgS8hnQn79Arj7PiHfvtsgn
ST_USER=auto02
ST_KEY=FfiBftkjgS8hnQn79Arj7PiHfvtsgn
user=qa04
key=s67aeYD6521pPgt7TknvGxKvF9WxNF
ST_USER=qa04
ST_KEY=s67aeYD6521pPgt7TknvGxKvF9WxNF

Comment: Sorry for the formatting. It appears to pass the variables correctly.

Comment: It would be better to edit your question to show additional information. In the question you can use code formatting to improve readability. Describe what's going wrong for the second user/key pair. You should add more debug output to see intermediate values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just add a simple `while` loop in the starting i.e.

```
while IFS=' ' read -r user key
 do
  Your whole script
 done < test.txt
```

Comment: So please correct me if I am doing this wrong but it appears to work for the first line in the test.txt file but the second line it will mess up. Also I had to add $user and $key into the variables where qa04 and the access key were. Is that correct?

Comment: I edited the comment above to put in what I think you suggested. Can you please let me know if this is correct? It only appears to work for the first line in the test.txt file. Thanks.

Comment: @bbelden What exactly happens with the second line? "it will mess up" is not a good description of the problem.

Comment: @bbelden please tell us what is the values of both for second input.

Comment: It appears as if the second line in test.txt is associated as the the 'user' variable instead of user and key. There is a space between the two but it appears it reads the second line as just the user and it fails to authenticate because its thinks 'qa03 F45oIYD6ndF3AgtAS372JaxKdefA5' is the user.

Comment: @bbelden no it is impossible it will read space separated words as different. You should add an commands `echo $user $password` to debug, and then show us the output.

Comment: user=auto02
key=FfiBftkjgS8hnQn79Arj7PiHfvtsgn
Starting check for files > 500000 bytes in the auto02 user account...
Container 4919d1c8-f5c7-448f-98ad-29d88f1a5a84
...finished check!
user=qa04 s67aeYD6521pPgt7TknvGxKvF9WxNF
key=

Comment: I apologize for the formatting. I added the echo $user and echo $ key and as you can see for user qa04 it appears that the user is the user and key leaving the key empty

Comment: @bbelden I updated the answer hopefully it will work.

Comment: That did it!! Thank you so much for the help!